# How to query objects created in current month but at least one year ago when creation date is a timestamp

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I have to build a SQL query to find objects which were created in current month (e.g. March) but at least one year ago. So I expect to fetch objects created in 03.2021, 03.2020, 03.2019 etc. Creation date is stored as Timestamp.

Is it possible to build such a query, or I have to fetch all objects created at least one year ago and check for their creation month in a loop (because I'm querying from Java)?
SQL scheme change is not allowed.

Comment: What have you tried? What about it did not work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MONTH(MyTimestamp)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND YEAR(MyTimestamp)<YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)`

Comment: @MauricePerry yes this is what I needed to solve my problem. Thanks. My head wasn't working good that day :)